# Does VB.Net have an equivalent to #pragma warning disable/restore?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-warnings

I've found a way to disable warnings for an entire VB.NET project, but that is very undesirable. I would like to disable a certain warning for the scope of one method at most. A line-by-line disable and restore would be better. For example, C# has `#pragma warning disable` (and `restore`). Does VB.NET have anything like this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, the answer is yes, yes it does.   The syntax is `#Disable Warning BC40000` and `#Enable Warning BC40000`

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14

Comment: Updated reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/disable-enable

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is no, the VB.NET compiler doesn't support suppression of warnings in such a manner. 
You would have to re-factor your VB.NET code or look at some other alternative like writing some of the code in C#.

Comment: VS 2015 allows #Disable Warning BCxxxxx for vb.net